# Passing in a different datatype into a method that expects a different datatype

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

With the XElement class, its constructor clearly takes the daya type XName as its first parameter, however, if I pass in a string, it works and I don't get a compile time error.

What's going on here exactly and how can I implment this in my own code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [implicit conversion from string to `XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx), basically. That's why this works too:

```
XName name = "element-name";
```

You can do this with your own types if you provide an appropriate [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) - but generally I *wouldn't* do this. (Note that you can provide the conversion either at the source type or the target type; in this case it's the target type (`XName`) which provides the conversion, not the source type (`string`).)

LINQ to XML does all kinds of interesting things with operator and conversion overloads which would *normally* be a bad idea, but happen to work really well in the context of XML. I particularly like the namespace handling:

```
XNamespace ns = "some namespace uri";
XName fullName = ns + "element-name";
```

Another useful oddity is the explicit conversions from XAttribute and XElement to various types; for example you can do:

```
XAttribute attribute = ...;
int? value = (int?) attribute;
```

The beauty of the nullability here is that if `attribute` is null, then the result will be too. This allows you to handle optional attributes (and elements) very cleanly.

Comment: I like the API for LINQ to XML, I think the use of implicit conversion works really well. Just looking for an excuse to use it somewhere. Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

`XName` has an a special [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx) defined. Implicit operators allow you to perform, well, implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

XName converts to and from string implicitly.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx):

XName does not contain any public constructors. Instead, this class provides an implicit conversion from String  that allows you to create an XName.

Comment: None of the overloads takes a string as the first parameter though - so this doesn't explain what's going on.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  -Yep, I was too fast on the gun. Answer corrected.